# Pear Mail debugging

Tags: debugging, email, pear

I have this stupid problem with Pear Mail:

I have script looking like that:

```
$params['host'] = $config['smtp_host'];
        $params['port'] = $config['smtp_port'];
        $params['auth'] = $config['smtp_auth'];
        $params['username'] = $config['smtp_username'];
        $params['password'] = $config['smtp_password'];
        $params['timeout'] = 10;

        $headers['From'] = 'Administrator <admin@admin.com>';
        $headers['To'] = '"'. $to .'" <' . $to . '>';
        $headers['Subject'] = "Bla";
        $headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
        $headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = "8bit";
        $mail_object = & Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
        $send = $mail_object->send($to, $headers, "hi");
        if(PEAR::isError($send))
            echo $send->getMessage();
```

And despite setting the timeout my script hangs for about 60-120 seconds, no error, nothing - the email is not being sent. I don't know how to debug it in any way ; / Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Variable $to is passed to a function which this code has inside. I know the object is being returned.

How can I check what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you only try to send one single mail for debugging
2. Install and activate [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)
3. At the beginning of your script, put a `xdebug_start_trace('/tmp/foo.xt')`
4. Run your script
5. Look at the function trace file in a text editor. The last line will show you which command hangs.

I suspect it's the network connect that hangs. You can run wireshark to see which packets get send, and if you get responses.